# How to Add Labels to Curves on a Graph

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following graph (and 2 similar ones) as shown below which I generated with MATLAB:

[image]

Rather than having a legend, I would like to have the curves labelled, so for exapmple in maths font you have 'Kn=0.0' floating somewhere below the blue curve, then a black line connects that to the curve, and so on for the others.  I am aware that this type of thing can be done in image editing software but was wondering if I could just add the image into a PDF document using LaTeX, is there some way of using LaTeX to add these labels in manually?  I will include the LaTeX code which I used to put the images onto a page of a PDF:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./pics/}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{epic}

%\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\usepackage[a4paper,total={170mm, 247mm}]{geometry}

%\usepackage{mdframed}
%\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,
width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
\vspace{5mm}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,
width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}\\
\vspace{5mm} 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,
width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}\\

\end{center}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(100,560){(a)} 
\put(100,370){(b)}
\put(100,180){(c)}
\put(250,16){$r$}

\put(120,460){
\begin{rotate}{90}
{$u_r / U_{\infty}$}
\end{rotate}}
\put(120,280){
\begin{rotate}{90}
{$u_\alpha / U_{\infty}$}
\end{rotate}}
\put(120,100){
\begin{rotate}{90}
{$\theta/U_{\infty}$}
\end{rotate}}
\end{picture}
%\vspace{-5mm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code puts the 3 graphs onto a page of a PDF document and labels them with axes placed appropriately using manual commands, so I was wondering if you could manually create lines to the curves with LaTex commands and so label them?

Comment: Your code is not compileable.

Comment: I've added the rest so it can be compiled hopefully, obviously the images are just any images.

Comment: Tip: most people will have images called `example-image`, `example-image-a`/`b`/`c`, and a few others (see documentation of `mwe` package) as part of their TeX distribution, so you can use those for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using picture mode in your original example, here an answer that uses picture commands to draw the labels and lines.

The labels require only an x and y coordinate, as you have already used for the axis text. The lines are drawn as a direction vector and a length (so not a start and end point as in PGF/TikZ). The direction vectors consist of x and y components between -6 and 6 (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture#Line_segments). For drawing a dotted line you can use `\multiput` which has a starting point, a difference vector to compute the next point, the number of segments, and a drawing command for each segment (for example a `\line`).

Note that you can use formatting commands inside of `\put`, such as color and text size.

MWE, drawn on top of a screenshot of your post:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[a4paper,total={170mm, 247mm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,
width=0.45\textwidth]{Dk1V2}\\
\end{center}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(100,180){(a)}
\put(250,16){$r$}

\put(120,100){
\begin{rotate}{90}
{$\theta/U_{\infty}$}
\end{rotate}}
\put(250,120){\tiny\color{blue}$K_n=0.0$}
\put(250,122){\line(-3,2){19}}
\put(220,100){\tiny\color{red}$K_n=0.2$}
\put(220,102){\color{gray}\line(-3,2){24}}
\put(190,80){\tiny\color{orange}$K_n=1.0$}
\multiput(200,85)(-1,1){24}
{\line(0,0){0.5}}
\end{picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Remark: of course this is not the most convenient solution, I just added it for completeness. Using PGF/TikZ such as in the other answer, or adding the labels in Matlab itself, would be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `axis cs` to describe a coordinate or node in an `axis` environment. I give an example using my own curves.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
    \tikzset{font=\small}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
    declare function={
        cV(\T,\TD,\a,\b) =
            (\a/(\T/\TD))^2 * exp(\b/(\T/\TD)) / (exp(\b/(\T/\TD))-1)^2;
    }
]
    \begin{axis}[
        legend style={at={(0.9,0.6)}},
        domain=0.001:3,
        samples=101,
        smooth,
        grid=both
    ]
        \addplot [blue]    {cV(x,0.75,1,1)};
        \addplot [red]   {cV(x,{(pi/6)^(-1/3)},1,1)};
        \addplot [yellow]   {cV(x,{(pi/3)^(-1/3)},1,1)};


    \node at (axis cs:1.5,0.8)(B){\color{blue}$K_n=0.0$};
    \draw [->](B.west)--++(160:0.35);
    \node at (axis cs:1.5,0.6)(Y){\color{yellow}$K_n=0.2$};
    \draw [->](Y.west)--++(160:0.55);
    \node at (axis cs:1.5,0.4)(R){\color{red}$K_n=1.0$};
    \draw [->](R.west)--++(160:0.62);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks about right, is it possible to soften the lines a bit and get rid of the arrowhead at the end?  Then I suppose I will just have to manually move them around until I get them where I need them for my document?

Comment: Use `\draw (B.west)--++(160:0.35);` to get rid of the arrowhead.

Comment: What does it mean `soften the lines` ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I was thinking to change the colour to orange and then having the line as a dashed line

Comment: No problem. `\draw [orange,densely dashed](B.west)--++(160:0.35);`